# Is there a way to retrieve inserted identity as well as some values from the query in an INSERT SELECT?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a situation in which I need to insert some values from a query into a table that has an identity PK. For some of the records, I need also to insert values in another table which has a 1-to-1 (partial) relationship:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    Id int identity primary key clustered, 
    Somevalue varchar(100),
    SomeOtherValue int)

CREATE TABLE B (Id int primary key clustered,
    SomeFlag bit)

DECLARE @inserted TABLE(NewId int, OldId)

INSERT INTO A (Somevalue) 
OUTPUT Inserted.Id into @inserted(NewId)
SELECT SomeValue
FROM A
WHERE <certain condition>

INSERT INTO B (Id, SomeFlag)
SELECT 
i.NewId, B.SomeFlag
FROM @inserted i
JOIN A ON <some condition>
JOIN B ON A.Id = B.Id
```

The problem is that the query from A in the first INSERT/SELECT returns records that can only be differentiated by the Id, which I cannot insert. Unfortunately **I cannot change the structure of the A table**, to insert the "previous" Id which would solve my problem.

Any idea that could lead to a solution?

Comment: Granted I am on cup of coffee number one, but I don't quite get what your after sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `INSERT ... OUTPUT ... SELECT ...` you can't output columns that are not in the target table. You can try `MERGE` instead:

```
MERGE INTO A as tgt
    USING   (SELECT Id, SomeValue FROM A WHERE <your conditions>) AS src
    ON      0 = 1
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT (SomeValue)
            VALUES (src.SomeValue)
            OUTPUT (inserted.Id, src.Id) -- this is your new Id / old Id mapping
            INTO    @inserted
;
```

Comment: @TT got things mixed up. Thanks

Comment: Nice idea. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

SCOPE_IDENTITY() returns the last identity value generated by the current session and current scope. You could stick that into a #table and use that to insert into B

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() as newid into #c
```

Though, your INSERT INTO B join conditions implies to me that the value in B is already known ?

Comment: Yes, thank you, but the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` only returns the latest id inserted and my sentence inserts a lot of records.